# Como puedo añadir la funcionalidad de scroll dentro de un proyecto de React?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un proyecto web hecho con React y Redux y funciona perfectamente. Ahora quiero añadir la funcionalidad de scroll ( desplazamiento horizontal). ¿Qué código debería añadir y donde exactamente? Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. Deberías dejar un poco de código de lo que has intentado y los errores que te ha dado, tal y como está, estás pidiendo que alguien te lo haga :)

Comment: No necesitas añadir ninguna librería para realizar eso, basta con que tu contenido desborde el contenedor principal y con un poco de css le das el scroll horizontal, solo seria de ayuda una librería externa si quieres dar un mejor estilo al scroll